# Why don't I get an EF5 Concurrency Error?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

In the database I'm working on the company keeps track of order numbers for each regional office.  I have a table named [Company] that has a single record for each regional office. This table has a field that holds the next available order number for that office. All orders are created in a single [Order] table. I realized it would be possible for more than one user at a given office to ask for a new order at the same time. I have everything set up for optimistic concurrency. The [Company] table has a column named RowModTracker used for concurrency purposes (see images at bottom for all the  properties in EF and SQL).

In my code below, I get the record for the regional office, increment the field that has the order number and put a copy in a local variable. Then I immediately save off the table. I would expect that if two users hit this method at the same time the first user to save off will get a valid order number. I would expect the second user to save off would get an  optimistic concurrency error and null should be returned (which causes a prompt that asks them to try again). The users tell me that a few times in the last eight months they have indeed gotten orders with the same order number. No messages and no errors happen until later in the process when they go to save the order and the unique constraint on the order number is violated.

I obviously don’t understand something fundamental about EF concurrency checking and I’m hoping someone can show me the light. I wrote a test version of GetNextOrderNumberAndUpdate where I wrapped a second using context around the first and it did indeed generate the expected concurrency error. It just doesn't seem to happen when two different clients do it.

```cs
 private int? TryToGetNextOrderNumber()
 {
     int? order_number;
      bool keep_trying = true;
      while (keep_trying)
      {
          order_number = _entityManager.GetNextOrderNumberAndUpdate();
          if (order_number != null) return order_number;
          keep_trying = KeepTryingForOrderNumberPrompt();
      }
      return null;
  }


  public int? GetNextOrderNumberAndUpdate()
  {
     try
     {     
         using (var db_context = new HotEntities(EntityConnectionString))
         {                   
              var hss_company = db_context.Companies.Find(HssCompanyInUse.HssCompanyId);
              int? next_order_num = ++hss_company.NextOrderNum;
              db_context.SaveChanges();
              return next_order_num;
          }
       }
       catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
       {
           return null;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return null; //actual code puts out an alert as well 
       }
  }
```

[image: EF5 Data Model View of Company Table]

[image: SSMS View of Company Table]

I am using Entity Framework 5 and SQL Server 2008 R2 with .NET 4.5.

## Edit

The test version looked like this, I've elided all the try/catch stuff it was the same as above

```
//Test force a failure 
using (HotEntities test_context = new HotEntities(EntityConnectionString))
{
    var test_hss_company = test_context.Companies.Find(HssCompanyInUse.HssCompanyId);
    int? test_next_order_num = ++test_hss_company.NextOrderNum;  
    //======= Normal Code ============
    using (var db_context = new HotEntities(EntityConnectionString))
    {
        var hss_company = db_context.Companies.Find(HssCompanyInUse.HssCompanyId);
        var next_order_num = ++hss_company.NextOrderNum;
        db_context.SaveChanges();
        return next_order_num;
    }
    //======= End Normal Code ============

test_context.SaveChanges(); //DbUpdateConcurrencyException exception would get thrown here
} //end for test using
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this: "I wrote a test version of GetNextOrderNumberAndUpdate where I wrapped a second using context around the first and it did indeed generate the expected concurrency error. It just doesn't seem to happen when two different clients do it." Does it mean that normally your clients share **the same** context?

Comment: No, I just meant from a single thread (really a single test method) I wrote a test where one context was opened and grabbed the record then in that thread I opened another context and grabbed the same record. In the second context I modified the order number and saved then record. Then in the first context I tried to save the record again with the same change. The second call to SaveChanges() threw a concurrency error. So I thought I had set it up correctly. I wouldn't know how to make different clients share a single context. I'll post the test version to make this clearer.